# Call a method from a form - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form to upload a file. I want to call a particular method in my controller when I press my submit button. This is probably a really simple thing but I'm really new to rails.

I have a method in my videos_controller called "upload_translation_handwritten"

Here is my form:

```
 %form{role: 'form'}
   .form-group 
     %label.h4{for: "handwrittenTranslation"} Upload Handwritten Translation
     %input#inputFile{name: 'translation', type: "file"}
     %button.btn.btn-default{type: "submit"} Upload
```

I have a route:

```
match 'users/:id/videos/:video_id/translate_video_handwritten' => 'videos#upload_translation_handwritten', via: 'post', as: :upload_translation_handwritten
```

I'm already at 'users/:id/videos/:video_id/translate_video_handwritten' and I want to call this other method that does a couple things then redirects to the same page with a little flash message. Right now, when I click "upload", nothing happens :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add this action url to form action, that means you will submit info from this form to that particular action of the controller and request will be handled according to code u have put in that particular action.

Comment: so would it just be %form{role: form, action: 'upload_translation_handwritten'} ?

Answer (score 0):

rails convention

- check form action(routing) and method(post)

  ```
  <form action="this" method="and this">...</form>
  ```

in routes.rb

```
 match "**/videos/:video_id" => "vidoes#edit", :as => :get          # upload form as html
 match "**/videos/:video_id/upload" => "videos#upload", :as => :post  # upload and redirect with flash
```

in videos_controller.rb

```
 def upload
     ...
     flash[:msg] = "Not suppported video format"
     render "edit"
 end
```

in upload_form.html.haml

```
- if flash[:msg]?
  = flash[:msg]
```

Comment: what would the action be? just 'upload' ? or would it be '/upload' ? or what?

Comment: <form action="**/videos/:video_id/upload">...</form>.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add url for attribute action. In your case, I think it is `%form{role: 'form', action: upload_translation_handwritten_user_video_path(user_id, video_id), method: :post}`. Please run `rake routes` to see right named helper

Answer (score 0):

Your route points out to the POST method only, 
You have to accept it for GET method also.
Change your route to

```
match 'users/:id/videos/:video_id/translate_video_handwritten' => 'videos#upload_translation_handwritten', as: :upload_translation_handwritten
```

Then You can able to view your Form, No need to give action in your form,

After Update Your Controller like this

```
def upload_translation_handwritten
    # Perform Your actions for both GET and POST 
    # check with 
    if request.post?
        # Add codes for actions after submission of form
    else
        # render your form
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by changing:

```
%form{role: 'form'}
```

TO

```
 =form_tag(:action => 'upload_translation_handwritten', :method => 'post')
```

Thank you everyone for your help!!